# Offseting all the values in a column by a base value

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a text file that contains data in the following format

```
1  0x5212cb03ca115ac0  0x3665fb5f1ac1
2  0x5212cb03ca115cc0  0x3665fb5f1ac7
3  0x5212cb03ca115ea0  0x3665fb5f1acd
4  0x5212cb03ca1160c0  0x3665fb5f1ad3
5  0x5212cb03ca1162a0  0x3665fb5f1ad9
6  0x5212cb03ca1164c0  0x3665fb5f1ade
7  0x5212cb03ca1166a0  0x3665fb5f1ae4
8  0x5212cb03ca1168a0  0x3665fb5f1aea
9  0x5212cb03ca116aa0  0x3665fb5f1af0
10  0x5212cb03ca116ca0  0x3665fb5f1af6
```

The columns 1,2 and 3 are in strict ascending order.I want to offset the values in columns 2 and 3 with the respective values in their ROW 0.That is to say every value in colum 2 (X) should be made (X - 0x5212cb03ca115ac0) and the same for column three.I tried to do this with awk

```
 awk '{print $1 "  "$2-0x5212cb03ca115ac0 "  "$3-0x3665fb5f1ac1 }' output.txt
```

I am getting

```
1  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
2  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
3  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
4  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
5  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
6  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
7  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
8  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
9  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
10  -5914012477826357248  -59811636910785
```

I don't expect negative values at all here.Why is this happening.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU awk then you need to pass `-n` in order for it to understand/parse non-decimal numbers in input. Otherwise you'll just be subtracting from 0.

Comment: How do I do that? awk -n ' statements ' output.txt doesn't seem to work

Comment: Exactly right. Also, some versions of awk support a strtoNum function so it would be `strtonum($2)`

Comment: @liv2hak: Works fine here. `$ awk -n '{print $1 "  "$2-0x5212cb03ca115ac0 "  "$3-0x3665fb5f1ac1 }' <<< '6  0x5212cb03ca1164c0  0x3665fb5f1ade'`
`6  3072  29`
Are you sure you're using GNU awk?